# Marklogic DHF & Grove setup fails

Tags: marklogic

I have been trying to setup MarkLogic Grove together with the Data Hub Framework according to following documentation.

[Grove + MarkLogic Data Hub](https://marklogic-community.github.io/grove/guides/data-hub-framework/)

Marklogic 10 + DHF installed successfully. However, I am stuck on the command 'gradlew.bat mlLoadModules' to setup the Grove Project with the DHF. After following the procedure described in the above link, I get the following when I enter the command:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
com.marklogic.appdeployer.AppConfig.setSchemasPath(Ljava/lang/String;)V

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

The environment I use is following

- OS version: Windows 10 Pro
- MarkLogic version: 10.0-4.4
- Marklogic DHF: 5.2.3
- Java: 11.0.8

Stacktrace does not reveal much more information, but I can provide if necessary. Can anybody help me get past this issue?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
com.marklogic.appdeployer.AppConfig.setSchemasPath(Ljava/lang/String;)V

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.marklogic.appdeployer.AppConfig.setSchemasPath(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.marklogic.hub.impl.HubConfigImpl.updateAppConfig(HubConfigImpl.java:1943)
    at com.marklogic.hub.impl.HubConfigImpl.setAppConfig(HubConfigImpl.java:1781)
    at com.marklogic.hub.impl.HubConfigImpl.setAppConfig(HubConfigImpl.java:1775)
    at com.marklogic.hub.impl.HubConfigImpl.hydrateAppConfigs(HubConfigImpl.java:1547)
    at com.marklogic.hub.impl.HubConfigImpl.loadConfigurationFromProperties(HubConfigImpl.java:1539)
    at com.marklogic.hub.impl.HubConfigImpl$loadConfigurationFromProperties.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.marklogic.gradle.DataHubPlugin.initializeProjectExtensions(DataHubPlugin.groovy:255)
    at com.marklogic.gradle.DataHubPlugin$initializeProjectExtensions$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.marklogic.gradle.DataHubPlugin.setupHub(DataHubPlugin.groovy:227)
    at com.marklogic.gradle.DataHubPlugin$setupHub.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.marklogic.gradle.DataHubPlugin.apply(DataHubPlugin.groovy:81)
    at com.marklogic.gradle.DataHubPlugin.apply(DataHubPlugin.groovy)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:177)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$300(DefaultPluginManager.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$2.execute(DefaultPluginManager.java:155)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$2.execute(DefaultPluginManager.java:152)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:152)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$3.run(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:151)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:225)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:148)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:186)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:48)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor$1.run(BuildScriptProcessor.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:186)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:226)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:186)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:695)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:41)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:302)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:210)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Here is the info output:

```
Initialized native services in: C:\Users\user\.gradle\native
Found daemon DaemonInfo{pid=21924, address=[51eb0c6d-8c82-4fa4-9d6f-f0beb6793351 port:58724, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1598342726580, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=0d2c5f12-d1e8-4a34-97e1-66de92fa4efa,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\user\.gradle\daemon,pid=21924,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=AT,-Duser.language=de,-Duser.variant]} however its context does not match the desired criteria.
Java home is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=C:\Programme\Java\jdk-11.0.8,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\user\.gradle\daemon,pid=24340,idleTimeout=null,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=AT,-Duser.language=de,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=0d2c5f12-d1e8-4a34-97e1-66de92fa4efa,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\user\.gradle\daemon,pid=21924,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=AT,-Duser.language=de,-Duser.variant]

  Looking for a different daemon...
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 18052). The daemon log file: C:\Users\user\.gradle\daemon\5.2.1\daemon-18052.out.log
Starting 5th build in daemon [uptime: 3 mins 19.744 secs, performance: 99%, no major garbage collections]
Using 8 worker leases.
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file 'C:\Users\user\DataHub_v2\settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:\Users\user\DataHub_v2\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'DataHub_v2']

> Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'DataHub_v2' using build file 'C:\Users\user\DataHub_v2\build.gradle'.
PropertiesPlugin:apply Loaded 37 properties from C:\Users\user\DataHub_v2/gradle.properties
PropertiesPlugin:apply Loaded 0 properties from C:\Users\user\DataHub_v2/gradle-local.properties
PropertiesPlugin:apply Skipping C:\Users\user\.gradle/gradle.properties because it does not exist
PropertiesPlugin:apply Loaded 0 properties from environment variables
PropertiesPlugin:apply Loaded 0 properties from system properties
PropertiesPlugin:apply Loaded 0 properties from the command line

Initializing ml-gradle
Admin interface host: localhost
Admin interface username: 
App host: localhost
REST admin username: 
App Services username: 
Module paths: src/main/ml-modules,src/main/ui-modules
Paths that data will be loaded from: src/main/ml-data,src/main/ui-data
Manage host: localhost
Manage username: 
Manage user with security role: 
Initializing ManageClient with manage config of: [ManageConfig host: localhost, port: 8002, username: , security username: ]
Finished initializing ml-gradle


Initializing ml-data-hub Gradle plugin
No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$940b5768] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
Channel 'org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@46a45e12.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
Config path: C:\Users\user\DataHub_v2\src\main\hub-internal-config
Config path: C:\Users\user\DataHub_v2\src\main\ml-config
Module paths: [C:\Users\user\DataHub_v2\src\main\ml-modules, C:\Users\user\DataHub_v2\src\main\ui-modules]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
com.marklogic.appdeployer.AppConfig.setSchemasPath(Ljava/lang/String;)V

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Comment: Can you provide full stacktrace with and anything else that might seem useful by adding --stacktrace or --info to your gradle command?

Comment: You can edit your question to provide the extra detail

Comment: Sorry, somehow did not notice your reply. Added stacktrace & info output now @grtjn

Comment: It seems something has changed since ml-gradle v4. mlSchemasPath has been removed. Looks like you need to drop that property, and move the files away from src/main/ui-schemas. Unfortunately the docs don't tell what the alternative is.. https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Property-reference

Comment: Ah, wait. You may be using mlSchemasPath instead of mlSchemaPaths. If the former doesn't work (ml-gradle 3.12 and less), use the latter instead (3.13 onwards)!

Comment: Hey, thanks @grtjn for the help. After many attempts with different ml-gradle versions, the only thing that actually got me anywhere was to remove the dependency from the build.gradle file.

This actually let me proceed, but could not figure out where to go from here. While this solves this issue, I dont know if this breaks anything  but will continue to investigate.

Comment: The TDE that comes out of the box with grove is just an example, not really used by the front-end.